# Hiding SplitView hamburger icon

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a SplitView in Overlay mode. Hamburger icon is overlaying my MainContent (this is what I wanted) Now I want it to auto hide when user does nothing. I want the same behaviour liek the MediaElement controls. If user drags the mosue controsl are visible and after some seconds they hide,

Comment: As a touch user, I'd like to encourage you not to show a hamburger icon only on mouse movement. UWP apps should be accessible with all input types, especially touch. We're not developing only for Macs here ;)

Comment: Please look at the following link http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/07/28/A-lap-around-Adaptive-Triggers.aspx   If this does not give enough information please add the xaml code of what you are trying to do.